# backbone route history with backgrid

Tags: backbone.js, javascript-framework, pushstate, backgrid

I am kind of new to backbone and I am building a grid using backgrid which uses backbone.
I have a grid which you can sort and fillter with 4 or 5 different fillters and also paging.

I came to the point where I want that  after the user filtered sorted and went to a diffrent url but then clicked the back button he will come to the last grid he created with the filtering sorting and paging. I couldn't find some examples I can use for this all I found is than backbones history pushstate can keep track of one action but how can it handle a few of them together?

Can you guide me on how should I do it?